# R syntax: make summary() understand the (string) result of paste0() as an object

Tags: r

I'm trying to run `lapply` to save many different datasets which should be named after the function argument (a string vector). I think I narrowed the problem down to the following **reproducible** example:

```
test_x <- c(1:3)
name <- paste0("test_","x")
summary(name)
```

where `x` would be my function argument thus I need `paste0()` to create the name.

How can I get rid of the `""` in `name`? I want summary to understand that `name` is actually `test_x`.

Here is the **non-reproducible** code as I intend to use it in case you think the mistake might be somewhere else:

```
savesum <- function(x){
out<-capture.output(summary(eba_results[[x]])) #following Rolands comment, we don't even need get()
name <- paste0("eba_",x,".txt")
cat(out,file=name,sep="\n",append=TRUE)
}
lapply(indicators,savesum)
```

Comment: This is not how you iterate over list elements. I don't understand why you use `assign` and you should use `results[[x]]` instead of `$`.

Comment: edited. Does this make more sense? It works in any case and I don't even need get(). Still was good to learn about it, won't delete the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `get` to get an object by name:

```
> summary(get(name))
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.0     1.5     2.0     2.0     2.5     3.0
```

read the help for `get` to see what it does.